# Can't access public class properties

Tags: c#, class, variables

I'm trying to create a new class that is supposed to have these variables in its code:

```
class Map
{
    // Variable declaration
    public int Width { get; set; } // Width of map in tiles
    public int Height { get; set; } // Height of map in tiles
    public int TileWidth { get; set; }
    public int TileHeight { get; set; }
}
```

but for some reason, after creating a new Map class in Game1.cs, I can't seem to acccess things such as Width and Height.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // etc...

    // Class initialization
    Map map = new Map();

    map.Width = 10; // Won't work, says it is a 'field' but used like a 'type'
}
```

I figure I'm not trying to set the property right, but I'm not sure how to actually do so.

I get two error messages when attempting the above:

> 'Deep.Game1.Map' is a 'field' but used like a 'type'

and

> Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: You need to use 'map.Width' in a method somewhere. I bet you're trying that outside a method in the class.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another class named `Map`? Maybe you're actually creating another class instance?

Comment: Did you have `map.Width w = 10;` or something? Be sure to include your exact code and enough code that we can reproduce the *same* error. Otherwise we are supplying wild guesses instead of qualified answers, and not helping you efficiently.

Comment: @EdS. I've added some code to the second snippet to clarify where the code is located in the file.

Comment: It seems Servy got the right answer. You can't assign to a member of `map` in that fashion, outside a constructor or method or accessor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't placed that code in an executable code block.  You can't just have a property setter floating around inside a type; it needs to be inside a method, constructor, etc.

If you want to set the width when initializing a field then you can use the object initializer syntax:

```
private Map map = new Map() {Width = 10};
```

Comment: _You haven't placed that code in an executable code block_  Good sleuthing for the specific error message!

Comment: @jltrem There aren't exactly a whole lot of ways to mess this up; and a quick test verifies which mistakes result in this particular error message.

Comment: +1 for executable code block, the term I was struggling to find.

Comment: I'm running this from LINQPad, but I expect it'd be the same as VS: putting `map.Width = 10;` in a class results in "Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration", not "a 'field' but used like a 'type'"

Comment: @TimS. Do you have a field called `map` in that class definition as well, that's before that line of code?  I get that error if the identifier can't be found, and this error (plus a 3rd) if it can be.

Comment: @TimS. I've played around with a few different ways of writing this, and I can get it to give me that error, but I also see the OP's as well.  The OP's is higher in the error list as well.  The edit to his question with his of course has now confirmed this answer.

Comment: @jltrem So it does. That explains it. I'm testing it in VS2012, and I see the "a 'field' but used like a 'type'" when the as-you-write-it (IntelliSense?) compiler produces its errors, but not when you build the project as a whole (in that case, it only shows the `'='` error).

Comment: @TimS. Ah, that would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
void Main()
{
    Map map = new Map();

    map.Width = 10;
}

class Map
{
    public int Width { get; set; } // Width of map in tiles
    public int Height { get; set; } // Height of map in tiles
    public int TileWidth { get; set; }
    public int TileHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe you have a missing `;` or `}` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you may be trying to set the property outside of a method. Try this:

```
class Game1
{
    Map map = new Map();

    public Game1()
    {
        map.Width = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the code that sets the `Width` property inside of a function? It needs to be. If it's not you'll see this error.

Also not sure if this line was typed out correctly, but it's missing a semi-colon:

```
 map.Width = 10
```